# How to disable back, home and recent buttons in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, navigation

I want to disable navigation buttons in a flutter app when the platform is Android.
I don't want to hide them. I want to disable even when the phone using physical navigation buttons.

Comment: have you found any solutions or workarounds??

Answer (score 1):

Back button can be disabled using [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) widget, I also think that the home button can be disabled using [hardware_buttons](https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons) package.